# How does css left / position works with bootstrap header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I dont' understand why css left does not work.

In my **html** I have page-header from boostrap

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Page-header</h1>
</div>

<div class="all charts">
   <div id="chart1"></div>
   <div id="chart2"></div>
</div>
```

and here is my **.css**

```
.page-header {
  background-color: none;
  width: 1000%;
}

.allcharts {
  left: 20px;
}

#chart1 {
  width: 2000%;
  float: left;
}
```

how come my allcharts ( want 20 px from the left ) and chart 1 and 2 are not taking the **left** postion from .css , they both have the same left position as my page-header even when I try to overwrite it in css

[image]

Comment: `width:1000% or 2000%` seems like a lot...is that a typo?

Comment: The position is static. Change to position:relative. Left doesn't know where it is unless it's relative, absolute, or fixed

Comment: @Paulie_D not quite I designed it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**position : absolute;** :: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

and
you have all and charts two different class

```
.all.charts {
  position : absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
```

OR

```
.all{
  position : absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
```

OR

```
.charts {
  position : absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I can answer my own question, but from Christina I got exactly what I want

```
.page-header {
  background-color: none;
  width: 1000%;
}

.allcharts {
  position : absolute;
  left: 20px;
}

#chart1 {
  width: 2000%;
  float: left;
}
```